# Centos 5 Full backup

Tags: centos, backup

so I have my dedicated server that is set to expire tomorrow. What I need to do is a full backup of everything, with the OS and everything on it. And when I say full backup, I mean a backup that can easily be restored to another dedicated server. I have installed lots of third party stuff such as red5, cpanel, and solusVM. I also have my IPtables, and php configured just the way I need it. What would be the best way to do this so I can restore it to another dedi? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like it's too late...

Comment: It can't be important stuff. Otherwise you would just run your backup a last time and be done with it.

Comment: Some of that software is commercially licensed and attached to the hardware.  You're going to have a hard time moving it.

Answer (score 2):

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=disk.img
```

This makes a complete copy of your system, that you in theory could just reverse on another box, and everything might run.

There are probably much better solutions, but this one is one of the simple ones.

There might need some additional command switches, as this is very basic.

It is of course very important that you **do not** do this while the OS is running - do it from some kind of rescue system or live OS.

Comment: That's the easiest way, but this should not be done in a running system where the file system is still active, as you are likely to get incosistencies.

Comment: @SvenW True - it should be done from some kind of rescue system. Edited original post.

Comment: You could also mount the img file and still access your data incase if you cannot recover reverse it on a new hardware

Comment: How would I restore it onto a new server? And can I pull individual files from that? Like php files from my html dir?

Comment: And when I run that I get 208782+0 records in
208782+0 records out
106896384 bytes (107 MB) copied, 1.21586 seconds, 87.9 MB/s.. Is my system not more than 107mb...

Comment: Maybe `/dev/sda1` is not your primary partition. Post output of `/etc/fstab` please.

Comment: And yes, you can pull single files from it by mounting the img file in another linux box. I cant remember the exact command for that atm.